# Do gravity and magnetic field change along a geographic latitude or not?

Tags: geophysics, geomagnetism, gravity

Along the same geographic latitude does magnetic field change or not, and the same for the gravitational field, does it change along a geographic latitude?  Please explain.

Answer (score 4):

They can both change along any direction.

Here's Earth's magnetic field strength in early 2014, from [ESA via NASA](https://climate.nasa.gov/news/3105/earths-magnetosphere-protecting-our-planet-from-harmful-space-energy/).

[image: Earth's magnetic field, early 2014]

And here's Earth's gravitational field strength courtesy of [NASA's GRACE satellite](https://www.earthdata.nasa.gov/learn/sensing-our-planet/matter-in-motion-earths-changing-gravity).  Note that the anomalies are quite exaggerated; the gravitational field is very close to uniform.

[image: Earth's gravitational field strength]